# KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS on EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Tags: ios, air, adobe, crash-reports

I have an Adobe Air app for IOS and it works fine for both Windows and Android but seems to hang and crash at random times on IOS.  The AIR debugger shows nothing when this happens.  I pulled the crash report from my iPhone and it is below.  I have read some of the other posts on this subject but they weren't really AIR apps so I was hoping for some pointers as to where I can start with this.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
Incident Identifier: 75387AA5-1AF2-4E2C-A92D-67174F8C2CDD  
CrashReporter Key:   47377582f4ab79d5f7814a5f67637bf02e00167d  
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1  
Process:         My App [2719]  
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/B136A542-E798-4A28-877F-5BBCA7A41361/My App.app/My App  
Identifier:      My App  
Version:         ??? (???)  
Code Type:       ARM (Native)  
Parent Process:  launchd [1]  

Date/Time:       2012-10-18 11:30:31.315 -0400  
OS Version:      iOS 6.0 (10A403)  
Report Version:  104  

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)  
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xf0e33c42  
Crashed Thread:  0  

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread  
Thread 0 Crashed:  
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x345eb5b0 objc_msgSend + 16  
1   My App                  0x00d08c4e 0x1000 + 13663310  
2   My App                  0x00b0f0c0 0x1000 + 11591872  
3   My App                  0x00b0e3ec 0x1000 + 11588588  
4   My App                  0x00b0d0d8 0x1000 + 11583704  
5   My App                  0x00b0d014 0x1000 + 11583508  
6   My App                  0x00b0cfe4 0x1000 + 11583460  
7   My App                  0x00886158 0x1000 + 8933720  
8   My App                  0x00886360 0x1000 + 8934240  
9   My App                  0x00893624 0x1000 + 8988196  
10  My App                  0x0089394c 0x1000 + 8989004  
11  My App                  0x00894068 0x1000 + 8990824  
12  My App                  0x00895734 0x1000 + 8996660  
13  My App                  0x00887960 0x1000 + 8939872  
14  My App                  0x00895228 0x1000 + 8995368  
15  My App                  0x0076dcc8 0x1000 + 7785672  
16  My App                  0x0073c640 0x1000 + 7583296  
17  My App                  0x00423308 0x1000 + 4334344  
18  My App                  0x0045eb40 0x1000 + 4578112  
19  My App                  0x0045d518 0x1000 + 4572440  
20  My App                  0x0045d1f0 0x1000 + 4571632  
21  My App                  0x00460260 0x1000 + 4584032  
22  My App                  0x00460420 0x1000 + 4584480  
23  My App                  0x000032e8 0x1000 + 8936  
24  My App                  0x00854b78 0x1000 + 8731512  
25  My App                  0x00855048 0x1000 + 8732744  
26  My App                  0x00854904 0x1000 + 8730884  
27  My App                  0x007cf0c0 0x1000 + 8184000  
28  My App                  0x007bacb4 0x1000 + 8101044  
29  My App                  0x0083855c 0x1000 + 8615260  
30  My App                  0x009c24d8 0x1000 + 10228952  
31  My App                  0x009c2c30 0x1000 + 10230832  
32  My App                  0x000d46fc 0x1000 + 866044  
33  My App                  0x00ce1b14 0x1000 + 13503252  
34  My App                  0x00ce2774 0x1000 + 13506420  
35  My App                  0x008c4540 0x1000 + 9188672  
36  My App                  0x008c524c 0x1000 + 9192012  
37  My App                  0x009a1838 0x1000 + 10094648  
38  QuartzCore                      0x3400806c CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch(unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 156  
39  QuartzCore                      0x34007fc4   CA::Display::IOMFBDisplayLink::callback(__IOMobileFramebuffer*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, void*) + 60  
40  IOMobileFramebuffer             0x3a04dfd4 IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 152  
41  IOKit                           0x39233446 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 190  
42  CoreFoundation                  0x34de85d8 __CFMachPortPerform + 116  
43  CoreFoundation                  0x34df3170__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32  
44  CoreFoundation                  0x34df3112 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134 
45  CoreFoundation                  0x34df1f94 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380  
46  CoreFoundation                  0x34d64eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352  
47  CoreFoundation                  0x34d64d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100  
48  GraphicsServices                0x35acd2e6 GSEventRunModal + 70  
49  UIKit                           0x379aa2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116  
50  My App                  0x008e4594 0x1000 + 9319828  
51  My App                  0x00d03360 0x1000 + 13640544  

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager  
Thread 1:  
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33add648 kevent64 + 24  
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x392064ec _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792  
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x391f8df4 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 32  

Thread 2 name:  WebThread  
Thread 2:  
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33adceb4 mach_msg_trap + 20  
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33add048 mach_msg + 36  
2   CoreFoundation                  0x34df3040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124  
3   CoreFoundation                  0x34df1d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878  
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34d64eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352  
5   CoreFoundation                  0x34d64d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100  
6   WebCore                         0x35b48a70 RunWebThread(void*) + 440  
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38eaa30e _pthread_start + 306  
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38eaa1d4 thread_start + 4  

Thread 3:  
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33adceb4 mach_msg_trap + 20  
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33add048 mach_msg + 36  
2   My App                  0x00876520 0x1000 + 8869152  
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38eaa30e _pthread_start + 306  
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38eaa1d4 thread_start + 4  

Thread 4:  
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33aed6a4 __semwait_signal + 24  
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38eaf3ce nanosleep + 138  
2   My App                  0x00a1fba4 0x1000 + 10611620  
3   My App                  0x00901ce4 0x1000 + 9440484  
4   My App                  0x00901c84 0x1000 + 9440388  
5   My App                  0x00a1fdb8 0x1000 + 10612152  
6   My App                  0x00a1fe0c 0x1000 + 10612236  
7   My App                  0x00a1fb38 0x1000 + 10611512  
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38eaa30e _pthread_start + 306  
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38eaa1d4 thread_start + 4  

Thread 5:  
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33aed08c __psynch_cvwait + 24  
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38ea2d2a _pthread_cond_wait + 642  
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38ea2aa0 pthread_cond_timedwait + 40  
3   My App                  0x00a1ffd4 0x1000 + 10612692  
4   My App                  0x000da46c 0x1000 + 889964  
5   My App                  0x00a1fdb8 0x1000 + 10612152  
6   My App                  0x00a1fe0c 0x1000 + 10612236  
7   My App                  0x00a1fb38 0x1000 + 10611512  
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38eaa30e _pthread_start + 306  
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38eaa1d4 thread_start + 4  

Thread 6:  
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33aedd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8  
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38e9fcf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14  
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38e9fa12 _pthread_wqthread + 362  
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38e9f8a0 start_wqthread + 4  

Thread 7:  
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33aedd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8  
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38e9fcf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14  
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38e9fa12 _pthread_wqthread + 362  
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38e9f8a0 start_wqthread + 4  

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):  
    r0: 0x0a6fc000    r1: 0x37df2920      r2: 0x37df2920      r3: 0x0a6fc000  
    r4: 0xf0e33c3a    r5: 0x079df030      r6: 0x079df438      r7: 0x2fdfe048  
    r8: 0x079df001    r9: 0x0df7ca48     r10: 0x00000008     r11: 0x079df040  
    ip: 0x00e0f1ec    sp: 0x2fdfe034      lr: 0x00d08c53      pc: 0x345eb5b0  
  cpsr: 0x200f0030
```

Comment: You should start by symbolicating your crash log so we can know what all those hex addresses are. Since you crash in objc_msgSend you are probably messaging an released object. See if you somehow can reproduce the crash with NSZombieEnabled. Not sure how that would work with an AIR app though...

Comment: A guess: You're using at least one native extension? Have you updated to the most recent version of the AIR SDK, which this week is 3.5.0.690? If you have the iPhone Configuration Utility, you can view additional information by connecting the iPad to your computer and opening the Utility's Console window.

Comment: I had this exact problem, it ended up being caused by a bug in a third-party native extension.  Once I removed the extension and code that pointed to it this error stopped.  Unfortunately the extension was only offered as pre-compiled code (.ane file) so I had no way to modify it, but I was able to find an alternative .ane file that did not have the bug.

Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 8):

While you archive your project for release, it is important you set some parameters under Project->Build Settings. Note that these settings must be set for release configuration in order for you to analyze crash log received from app store.

- Generate Debug Symbols: YES
- Deployment Post Processing: YES
- Strip Linked Product: YES
- Debug Information Format: DWARF with dSym file
- Use separate strip: YES
- Strip debug symbols during Copy: NO

Your app must be archived using above settings.
As soon as you reproduce crash, take the crash log file.
Import it into XCode organizer by going to Organizer->Devices->Device Logs->Drag the file from finder and drop here. When you open the log, it should show you function name in your code and line that caused the crash.

Note that correct dSym file for your build is important. It must be present in one of your user directories for correct code to be pointed out. Read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-SECTION2) to know about it if above doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: This is an Adobe AIR app so I don't believe I have access to these build settings, and I can't seem to find any .dsym file that was created by the AIR-to-IOS compiler.  If I do have access to these will it allow me to see the specific lines from the AIR app or ANE file which are causing the crash?

Comment: Sorry I ignored this fact. Could this help then? http://blogs.adobe.com/rajorshi/2011/11/18/debugging-native-extensions-for-air-ios/

Comment: This didn't help me directly but I'll give you the bounty since it was the only answer.  The native debugging stuff looks like it could have been useful but I was unable to get it working.

Comment: glad could point to correct stuff. Adobe AIR was a gray area for myself too, or I wouldn't have overlooked it in the beginning. Thanks for the bounty!